# Why is Path.resolve() not working in my code?

Tags: java, path, nio

Here is my code:

```
public static Path changePath(Path pathInput) throws IOException
{
  Path pathOutput = pathInput;
  System.out.println(pathOutput);
  pathOutput.resolve("test.xxx");
  System.out.println(pathOutput);
  return pathOutput;
}
```

pathInput is a directory.
pathOutput should return a file with the directory + / + test.xxx

Both System.out.println lines output the same string; the pathInput!

Perhaps the problem lies with the line `pathOutput = pathInput`. I tried to create a new Path() object but it said that you couldn't.

Regards.

Comment: IMHO `Path.resolve()` is broken in java. E.g here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve(java.nio.file.Path) it says: `If the other parameter is an absolute path then this method trivially returns other. If other is an empty path then this method trivially returns this path. Otherwise this method considers this path to be a directory and resolves the given path against this path.` which is complete nonsense and many times results in incorrect paths being created as a result. It should fail if `other` is not one thing.

Answer (score 2):

`Path` is immutable. [As the javadoc states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)

> Implementations of this interface are immutable and safe for use by
>   multiple concurrent threads.

Reassign it

```
pathOutput = pathOutput.resolve("test.xxx");
```

before you return it.

Comment: Something so silly! Thank you, I've clearly been writing code for too long.